# List of List of Numbers with a Bounded wildcard type

Tags: java, generics

If I have this,

```
Collection<? extends Number> c = new ArrayList<>();
c.add(new Integer(1)); // Compile time error
```

Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add integers to it.

But if I do like,

```
List<List<? extends Number>> history = new ArrayList<>();

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
integers.add(new Integer(1));

List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
doubles.add(new Double(2));

history.add(integers); // This is allowed
history.add(doubles);  // This is allowed
```

Why the addition in the 2nd example is allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Collection<? extends ...>
c.add(...);
```

A collection with a lower bound cannot be added to.

```
List<List<...>> history;
history.add(...);      // Allowed
```

The outer list has a concrete type. The `? extends` wildcard is inside the inner list, but it's irrelevant since you're adding to the outer list. I've replaced the wildcard with `...` since it doesn't matter what it is when you're calling `history.add()`.

If the outer list had a wildcard bound then adding would fail.

```
List<? extends List<...>> history;
history.add(...);      // NOT allowed
```

Comment: +1. Few clarifications though.The outer list has a concrete type. How? Doesn't the outer list dependent on the unknown type parameter of the inner. Please suggest.

Comment: You can call `add()` on a `List<X>` but not a `List<? extends X>`. It's fine even if `X` itself contains a wildcard. `List<List<? extends Y>>` is still a `List<X>` where `X = List<? extends Y>`.